# Prevent page load every time on Whatsapp Automation using selenium- C#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, whatsapp

I am developing a automation of Whatsapp using silenium and C# with web whatsapp for my personal reason.
I am currently stuck in 2 problems

1. My  number get blocked on sending message where as i had already places delay of 10-15 seconds in each request.
2. Each time my page reload on whastapp call i need to prevent it and want to place message directly any way for it ?
   Note- numbers are dynamic and coming from DB.

Code

```
   private void msgnew(string number, string message, int len, string oldnumber)
    {
       
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + number + "&text=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(message) + "&lang=en&app_absent=1");
      
    
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button._4sWnG>span")).Click();//Click SEND Arrow Button
                                                                       
 
    }
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: I think you should have the selenium act more like a user would. A user would never send a message by typing out https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + number + "&text=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(message) + "&lang=en&app_absent=1 in the url. You should probably have selenium navigate once to the main url then have it send the message by interacting with the ui and sending keys to the message box.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in js as:

```
js = """
            var [ num ] = [ arguments[0]];
            function openChat (t) {
                var e;
                t&&((e=document.createElement("a")).setAttribute("href","whatsapp://send?phone="+t),document.body.appendChild(e),e.click(),e.outerHTML="",setTimeout(1,1e3))

                      }
            return openChat(num)
        """
```

now use ExecuteScript ,

in python :

```
            js = """
            var [ num ] = [ arguments[0]];
            function openChat (t) {
                var e;
                t&&((e=document.createElement("a")).setAttribute("href","whatsapp://send?phone="+t),document.body.appendChild(e),e.click(),e.outerHTML="",setTimeout(1,1e3))
                
                      }
            return openChat(num)
        """
        self.driver.execute_script(js, number)
```

and to check if current number opened:

```
            js = """
        var [ t ] = [ arguments[0]];
        if (document.querySelectorAll(`[data-id*="${t}@"]`).length > 0 || (document.querySelector(`#main header span[title]`) && document.querySelector(`#main header span[title]`).title.replace(/\s/g, '').replace('-', '').replace('+','').replace('⁩', '').replace('⁦', '') == t)
        ){
                    return true
                }
        """
        r = self.driver.execute_script(js, number)
```

r will be true if open current number.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).